# Error: Failed to transpile program ionic2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

ionic cordova build android
    [WARN] Detected @ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular in your package.json.

```
       As of CLI 3.8, it is no longer needed. You can uninstall it:

       npm uninstall --save-dev --save-exact @ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-a

[INFO] Running app-scripts build: --platform android --target cordova

[15:38:32]  build dev started ...
[15:38:32]  clean started ...
[15:38:32]  clean finished in 1 ms
[15:38:32]  copy started ...
[15:38:32]  transpile started ...
[15:38:39]  typescript: C:/Users/NATALIA/Pictures/mdp365-ionic3/src/aponent.spec.ts, line: 6
            Cannot find name 'describe'.

       L5:  beforeEach(() => {
       L6:    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
       L7:      declarations: [

[15:38:39]  typescript: C:/Users/NATALIA/Pictures/mdp365-ionic3/src/aponent.spec.ts, line: 7
            Cannot find name 'beforeEach'.

       L6:  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
       L7:    declarations: [
       L8:      AppComponent

[15:38:39]  typescript: C:/Users/NATALIA/Pictures/mdp365-ionic3/src/aponent.spec.ts, line: 16
            Cannot find name 'it'.

      L15:  const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
      L16:  const app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
      L17:  expect(app).toBeTruthy();

[15:38:39]  typescript: C:/Users/NATALIA/Pictures/mdp365-ionic3/src/aponent.spec.ts, line: 19
            Cannot find name 'expect'.

      L18:    }));
      L20:    it(`should have as title 'app works!'`, async(() => {

[15:38:39]  typescript: C:/Users/NATALIA/Pictures/mdp365-ionic3/src/aponent.spec.ts, line: 22
            Cannot find name 'it'.

      L21:  const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
      L22:  const app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
      L23:  expect(app.title).toEqual('app works!');

[15:38:39]  typescript: C:/Users/NATALIA/Pictures/mdp365-ionic3/src/aponent.spec.ts, line: 25
            Cannot find name 'expect'.

      L24:    }));
      L26:    it('should render title in a h1 tag', async(() => {

[15:38:39]  typescript: C:/Users/NATALIA/Pictures/mdp365-ionic3/src/aponent.spec.ts, line: 28
            Cannot find name 'it'.

      L27:  const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
      L28:  fixture.detectChanges();
      L29:  const compiled = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;

[15:38:39]  typescript: C:/Users/NATALIA/Pictures/mdp365-ionic3/src/aponent.spec.ts, line: 32
            Cannot find name 'expect'.

      L31:    }));
      L32:  });
```

Error: Failed to transpile program
        at BuildError.Error (native)
        at new BuildError (C:\Users\NATALIA\Pictures\mdp365-ionic3\node_moic\app-scripts\dist\util\errors.js:16:28)
        at C:\Users\NATALIA\Pictures\mdp365-ionic3\node_modules\@ionic\appist\transpile.js:137:20
        at transpileWorker (C:\Users\NATALIA\Pictures\mdp365-ionic3\node_mnic\app-scripts\dist\transpile.js:103:12)
        at Object.transpile (C:\Users\NATALIA\Pictures\mdp365-ionic3\node_onic\app-scripts\dist\transpile.js:61:12)
        at buildProject (C:\Usersenter code here\NATALIA\Pictures\mdp365-ionic3\node_modu\app-scripts\dist\build.js:97:78)
        at C:\Users\NATALIA\Pictures\mdp365-ionic3\node_modules\@ionic\appist\build.js:47:16

Answer (score 0):

All of the missing members look related to your test framework (I'm guessing it is Jasmine or Jest):

```
Cannot find name 'describe'.
...
Cannot find name 'it'.
```

You need to ensure that:

1. you have the framework available (in your `package.json`, etc)
2. have imported the framework in your spec file (import/require etc)